# unfartunately app has stopped, random numbers crash

Tags: java, android, random

but i achieved to get no errors in code but when i try to execute in emulator it says unfartunately app has stopped.
The problem have to be in this part, because it stops only when klassenNr=6

```
int zufallsNr1;
int zufallsNr2 = 300;
int zufallsNr3 = 300;
int zufallsNr4 = 300;
int zufallsNr5 = 300;

if (klassenNr == 6) {
    Random zufall = new Random();
    int zufallsNr1 = zufall.nextInt(name[4].length);
    while (zufallsNr1 == zufallsNr2 && zufallsNr2 == 300) {
        zufallsNr2 = zufall.nextInt(name[4].length);
    }
    while (zufallsNr3 == zufallsNr2 && zufallsNr3 == zufallsNr1 && zufallsNr3 == 300) {
        zufallsNr3 = zufall.nextInt(name[4].length);
    }
    while (zufallsNr4 == zufallsNr2 && zufallsNr4 == zufallsNr1 && zufallsNr4 == zufallsNr3
                && zufallsNr4 == 300) {
        zufallsNr4 = zufall.nextInt(name[4].length);
    }
    while (zufallsNr5 == zufallsNr2 && zufallsNr5 == zufallsNr1 && zufallsNr5 == zufallsNr3
                && zufallsNr5 == zufallsNr4 && zufallsNr5 == 300) {
        zufallsNr5 = zufall.nextInt(name[4].length);
    }

    valuelist = new String[] { name[4][zufallsNr1], 
            name[4][zufallsNr2], name[4][zufallsNr3],
            name[4][zufallsNr4], name[4][zufallsNr5] };

} else {
    if (klassenNr == 5) {
        valuelist = topographienamen;
    } else {
        valuelist = name[klassenNr];
    }
}
```

300 is much more than name[4].length

logcat:

```
05-30 01:46:09.725: I/ActivityManager(297): START u0 {cmp=com.jafapp.igeo/.FuenfteActivity (has extras)} from pid 12533
05-30 01:46:09.738: W/WindowManager(297): Failure taking screenshot for (328x583) to layer 21020
05-30 01:46:10.355: D/AndroidRuntime(12533): Shutting down VM
05-30 01:46:10.406: W/dalvikvm(12533): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jafapp.igeo/com.jafapp.igeo.FuenfteActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=254; index=300
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=254; index=300
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at com.jafapp.igeo.FuenfteActivity.onCreate(FuenfteActivity.java:449)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-30 01:46:10.506: E/AndroidRuntime(12533):    ... 11 more
05-30 01:46:10.585: W/ActivityManager(297):   Force finishing activity com.jafapp.igeo/.FuenfteActivity
05-30 01:46:10.645: W/ActivityManager(297):   Force finishing activity com.jafapp.igeo/.KlassenlisteActivity
05-30 01:46:11.189: W/ActivityManager(297): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{40fbe7f0 u0 com.jafapp.igeo/.FuenfteActivity}
05-30 01:46:11.255: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
05-30 01:46:11.775: E/SurfaceFlinger(37): ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

Comment: Copy your stack trace from log cat in here.

Comment: maybe silly question but ...how?

Comment: What is line 449 of FuenfteActivity? The error occurred there.

Comment: but zufallsNr1/2/3/4/5 cant be bigger than the length...

Comment: and with the while i wanted to be sure the nextInt arent the same

Comment: Please dont put code in comments, edit your post and add the relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code loops as long as ALL the variables are 300. But if ONE of them is not 300 which is the case after the first loop the rest will never loop at all. So in the end when your 254 long String[] array is acccessed, most of them will be 300 which causes the Exception.